# Import data from mbpoll application to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get data from power analyzer with mbpoll application. But my code gives an error 'can't create an object'. I have tried to create other objects and it worked. It doesn't work on mbpoll. Here it is the link to my Mbpoll document. Appreciate all helps that i can get.

Mbpoll program-->https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cOr95sNdKO_o7_ox-T3JLY3XBz5kXYwT?usp=sharing

```
Public doc1 As Object
Public doc2 As Object
Public app As Object
Dim res As Integer
Dim n As Integer


Public Sub StartModbusPoll_Click()
   Set app = CreateObject("Mbpoll.Application")
   Set doc1 = CreateObject("Mbpoll.Document")
   Set doc2 = CreateObject("Mbpoll.Document")

   ' Read 10 Holding Registers every 1000ms
   res = doc1.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, 0, 10, 1000)
   ' Read 10 Coil Status every 1000ms
   res = doc2.ReadCoils(1, 0, 10, 1000)
   ' doc1.ShowWindow()


   app.Connection = 1 ' Modbus TCP/IP
   app.IPAddress = "192.168.37.100" 
   app.ServerPort = 502
   app.ConnectTimeout = 1000
   res = app.OpenConnection()
End Sub


Public Sub Read_Click()
   Cells(5, 7) = doc1.ReadResult() 'Show results for the requests
   Cells(6, 7) = doc2.ReadResult()
      
   For n = 0 To 9
      Cells(5 + n, 2) = doc1.Registers(n)
   Next n


   For n = 0 To 9
      Cells(18 + n, 2) = doc2.Coils(n)
   Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, a couple of comments: the link you posted is private, you should make it public if you want it to be accessible. About the `can't create object` error: are you sure `app.IPAddress = "127.0.0.1" ` is correct? By the looks of it you should be connecting to the IP address of the power meter, not your localhost...

Comment: Hello, i have already tried those things you said but didn't worked. Sorry about the IPAddress i forget to change it before post it. It was my power analyzer's(192.168.37.100). Thanks for your comment.

Comment: so you mean you have tried connecting from the same computer and reading Modbus registers **with a different application** and it works fine? The link is still private by the way

Comment: No. I was getting ActiveX cant create the object problem. I just tried to create any other object to see if there is a problem on activeX.